# Linear regression plot is really bad

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

observations that are different from each other so i run regression again but for only one cluster.[But it also came out wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFibN.jpg) What exactly is wrong here? I'll also have to point out that i am still new to this (linerear regression etc.) so my understanding of all this is still bad. How can i fix this plot and please if it's possible try to explain why it's wrong.

Code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)


kmeans.cluster_centers_

kmeans.labels_
n,y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 0)



plt.scatter(X.iloc[:, 1], Y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing *multiple linear regression*, since you have 2 input features (`'Age'`, `'Annual Income (k$)'`) that try to predict the output feature (`'Spending Score (1-100)'`). You need to plot this data in 3D, in order to properly visualize the regression.

Even though I can't test your code without the data, something like this should work (after training the model):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(X.iloc[:, 0], X.iloc[:, 1], Y)
ax.plot(X.iloc[:, 0], X.iloc[:, 1], y_pred, color='red')

ax.set_xlabel('Age')
ax.set_ylabel('Annual Income')
ax.set_zlabel('Spending Score')
```

Comment: Thank you jfaccioni it's much better now. I am aware that it's multiple linear regression but i forgot to mention it. I didn't realise that i had to plot it differently from a linear regression but it makes sense now to plot it in 3D.